# Duplicate question changes - can't mark duplicates by same user

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, duplicate-questions, close-reasons

The changed duplicate functionality (just now?) won't let us mark a duplicate where an asker asks the same question twice in an effort to get a response. eg:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/1433426

This is because neither question presently has answers or upvotes.

What's the preferred action in this event?

(I get that the example is probably too localized anyway, but the question still stands).

Comment: This is *exactly* what the site needs, making it even harder to close as duplicate. Oh look, we're at 4.4 million questions now!

Comment: WTF is this new feature.. this awful. Can't mark as a duplicate of a question without an upvoted or accepted answer? WHHHHATTTT?!??!!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: As with all new features, there will be bugs. Calm down for a moment, it'll all get cleared up in a day or two. This happens quite often.

Comment: @Manishearth: Actually, no, it won't. My problem is with the new feature as designed, not any bug. But we have [a thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165928/we-should-be-able-to-close-questions-as-duplicates-of-any-question?lq=1) for that now.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I already saw that (upvoted). It may not classify as a "bug" (this one does though), but I really doubt that it won't get fixed soon. The point behind testing these things on your users is to get good feedback.

Comment: @Manishearth: And my earlier comment was, in part, _that exact feedback_ ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Well, it looked more of a rant to me, since there already was a long meta post on the same matter :/

Comment: @Manishearth: Not at that time, there wasn't! I posted [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165926/where-is-the-meta-post-regarding-the-duplicate-feature-changes?lq=1) immediately thereafter, and everything started from there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just a thought - A fix might be simply to allow the duplicate regardless if the asker is the same for both questions.

Comment: Yeah, this was supposed to be the case. Looks like that check was missed.

Comment: This will be fixed in the next production build, sometime this afternoon Eastern Time, /cc @Shog9

Comment: @JarrodDixon Ugh, can we disable this on Meta too? It makes consolidating bug reports obnoxious.

Comment: @TimStone great point - on metas, will allow any question to be chosen as the original.

Comment: @JarrodDixon Fantastic, thanks!