# Closing consecutive exact duplicate bad questions from the same user got harder

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, close-reasons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Duplicate question changes - can’t mark duplicates by same user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165852/duplicate-question-changes-cant-mark-duplicates-by-same-user)

New users who tend to ask bad question sometimes also post the same question multiple times. So far they were closed pretty quickly, because it's easy to identify literally **exact** duplicates. Now it's impossible unless the question is answered and the answer is upvoted/accepted:

[image: The message]

So the duplicate question sticks around much longer. I know there usually are other reasons to close it, otherwise the original would be answered, but now if the dupe will at all be closed, it will take much more time, which I consider a bad thing.

I see this as a problem, although I do understand the logic behind this behavior. The problem has to be solved in some way. Perhaps it should be handled at the moment of posting (by computing the degree of similarity with other posts of the same user, for instance). This could be done for users with <100 reputation or something. Or just bring back the old dupe-close maybe?

Or is it the established view that the extended life time of low quality content is not a problem compared to closed questions that are duplicate of unanswered questions?

P.S. Would be ironic if *this* is a duplicate.

Comment: @TimStone Hell yeah :) the helpfullness of "related" suggestions never ceases to amaze me.