# How to handle duplicates of questions that just didn't receive an answer?

Tags: support, closed-questions

It seems that you can no longer handle duplicates of questions that haven't received an answer through close votes — unless you're a moderator, or both questions are by the same user.

*How* are we then supposed to handle them, then?

<s>Three</s> Two main possible scenarios that come to mind:

- Questions independently asked within minutes of one another
- [Questions that simply did not receive an answer though no fault of the question itself or the community](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?page=7000&tab=noanswers)
- <s>Repeat questions by people who *really* want an answer yesterday</s>
  ([fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165852/duplicate-question-changes-cant-mark-duplicates-by-same-user))

Comment: It would nice if there were some way to do this and re-emphasize the original. I don't see how multiple versions of the same unanswered question helps anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you provide the primary answer in your question:

> unless you're a moderator, or both questions are by the same user.

I asked a [very similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201849/213634) earlier today (but with an active example) , and part of [the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/201868/213634) I got from a moderator was:

> Others might require some very rare and specific knowledge, and just haven't gotten enough visibility. You can flag one for moderator attention, point to the other and let them have a look.

In cases where the two duplicates were asked within a short timeframe *and were equally good*, I would comment in both with a link to the other, and then try to ensure that if/when one of them received an answer that the other one would then be closed as the duplicate. Or, if they both received answers within the same short timeframe, I would then probably flag either as a duplicate.

If either question or answer(s) is discernably poorer on either side, that question should obviously be the one marked as a duplicate of the better.