# Where is the Meta post regarding the "duplicate" feature changes?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I can't find the feature request / bug report on Meta Stack Overflow that led to changes to the Mark As Duplicate system over the past few days.

Could you point me to it, please?

I would like to cast a vote on it, after-the-fact, since I have found the changes impeding my ability to perform the 10/15-daily "*Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object*" dup close task that keeps the [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) tag from completely imploding.

Comment: As far as I know, there hasn't been any official announcement yet. Just a series of gradual changes.

Comment: I see. So who requested the change? What was wrong with the old system?

Comment: 10 to 15? Really? What was the target of all the previous close-as-dupe votes before this week?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: Usually the top hit in the "Related" sidebar, which no longer shows up in the list of suggested duplicates, and which often don't have upvoted answers (because the whole topic sucks and draws total derision) so are no longer accepted. I'd like to know the rationale for this decision. Quality/quantity of answers has _nothing_ to do with whether a question has been asked before.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: This particular one, I don't believe anyone did. I'm curious what their reasoning was behind it. But some other changes include the new dialog, the `[duplicate]` appendage, and changed the info box to say "marked as duplicate". This is apparently just the next phase of whatever "duplicate campaign" they appear to be on. I'm sure they'll let us know everything when they're done with their evil plans.

Comment: @animuson: Might have been nice to have been consulted, is all I'm saying! I know they don't _have_ to, but this is a community of hundreds of thousands of software developers, so you'd think we could be useful.

Comment: You might find [the most recent podcast](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/01/podcast-41-neither-of-us-have-muscles/) interesting listening. Joel was pushing back against what he sees as excessive closures. Not dupes specifically, as far as I remember, but.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: Joel's more than welcome to start actually navigating around the hundreds of dups posted _per day_, if he thinks we're over-closing. SO's database has totalled ballooned to the point at which certain tags are nigh-on worthless, in my view. Being able to close things helps _a little_. Regardless, this new mechanism doesn't appear to make any sense, to me. Might as well just remove the feature entirely if that's the goal.

Comment: I don't know how I feel about this yet, Lightness - I can imagine getting pretty frustrated when a good (in my eyes) dupe closure is prevented, but I haven't run into one of those yet, and I vote to close *a lot*. I think [the other question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165928/we-should-be-able-to-close-questions-as-duplicates-of-any-question), that you've seen, is a better place to discuss this change. It wasn't preannounced.

Comment: Well I experienced it just before posting this question. It's very frustrating. Dup-closing all these stupid SQL didn't-do-error-checking questions was time-consuming enough already. I really don't need to have to get past an extra filter layer.

Comment: Via @Shog9: it's here:

- [Changes to close as duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165933/changes-to-close-as-duplicate)

Comment: FFS. Trying to post that as an _answer_. Of course, the system won't let me. It insists on it being a comment. Sigh.

Comment: Eh, my comment shoulda been an answer anyway I guess. Moved.

Comment: @Shog9: Ta, Shogilator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here you go](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165933/changes-to-close-as-duplicate).

There are about 5-6 different changes in the pipeline here, and there'll be some more info once they're all rolled out - but you're right, this should've been announced sooner.